# if you gaze long enough into strtok, strtok will gaze back into you

Tags: c, strings, parsing

The `tokenise` function below splits a given string at the indicated delimiters. As with [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), it modifies the string by adding `'\0'`s at the end of each token.

A pointer to the start of each token string is placed into the output array.

```
#include <string.h>

/* 
 * Wrapper around strtok
 * 
 * Splits a string at characters in "delimiters", writing each token to "output".
 * Delimiter characters in the source are overwritten with '\0'.
 * Stops tokenising if "output_size" is reached.
 * 
 * Returns 0 if "source", "delimiters", or "output" are NULL.
 * Returns 0 if "output_size" is 0.
 *
 * "source" must NOT be a string literal (modifying one is undefined behaviour).
 * "output" must be at least "output_size" long.
 * 
 * Example usage: 
 * char[] src = "a b c";
 * char* out[3]; 
 * size_t n = tokenise(src, " ", out, 3);
 * 
 */
size_t tokenise(char* source, char const* delimiters, char** output, size_t output_size)
{
    if (!source) return 0;
    if (!delimiters) return 0;
    if (!output) return 0;
    if (output_size < 1) return 0;

    char* const* start = output;
    char* const* end = output + output_size;

    *output = strtok(source, delimiters);

    while (*output && ++output != end)
        *output = strtok(NULL, delimiters);

    return output - start;
}


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void test(bool conditional)
{
    if (!conditional)
        printf("failed!\n");
}

void test_null_source_returns_zero()
{
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(NULL, " ", output, 1) == 0);
}

void test_null_delimiters_returns_zero()
{
    char source[] = " ";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, NULL, output, 1) == 0);
    test(source[0] != '\0');
}

void test_null_output_returns_zero()
{
    char source[] = " ";
    test(tokenise(source, " ", NULL, 1) == 0);
    test(source[0] != '\0');
}

void test_zero_output_size_returns_zero()
{
    char source[] = " ";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 0) == 0);
    test(source[0] != '\0');
}

void test_empty_source_returns_zero()
{
    char source[] = "";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 1) == 0);
}

void test_source_without_delimiters_returns_one()
{
    char source[] = "sdlfkj";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 1) == 1);
}

void test_source_with_only_delimiters_returns_zero()
{
    char source[] = "     ";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 1) == 0);
    test(source[0] != '\0');
}

void test_empty_delimiters_returns_one()
{
    char source[] = "abc";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, "", output, 1) == 1);
    test(strcmp(output[0], source) == 0);
}

void test_source_starts_with_delimiter()
{
    char source[] = "  abc";
    char* output[1];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 1) == 1);
    test(source[0] != '\0');
    test(strcmp(output[0], "abc") == 0);
}

void test_source_ends_with_delimiter()
{
    char source[] = "a 123  ";
    char* output[2];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 2) == 2);
    test(source[5] == '\0');
    test(source[6] != '\0');
    test(strcmp(output[0], "a") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[1], "123") == 0);
}

void test_source_starts_and_ends_with_delimiter()
{
    char source[] = " a  bbb cccc dd ";
    char* output[4];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 4) == 4);
    test(source[3] != '\0');
    test(strcmp(output[0], "a") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[1], "bbb") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[2], "cccc") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[3], "dd") == 0);
}

void test_small_output_size_stops_tokenising()
{
    char source[] = "a b c d";
    char* output[2];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 2) == 2);
    test(source[3] == '\0');
    test(source[5] != '\0');
    test(strcmp(output[0], "a") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[1], "b") == 0);
}

void test_large_output_size_stops_at_end_of_source()
{
    char source[] = "a b c d";
    char* output[53];
    test(tokenise(source, " ", output, 53) == 4);
    test(strcmp(output[0], "a") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[1], "b") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[2], "c") == 0);
    test(strcmp(output[3], "d") == 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    test_null_source_returns_zero();
    test_null_delimiters_returns_zero();
    test_null_output_returns_zero();
    test_zero_output_size_returns_zero();
    test_empty_source_returns_zero();
    test_source_without_delimiters_returns_one();
    test_source_with_only_delimiters_returns_zero();
    test_empty_delimiters_returns_one();
    test_source_starts_with_delimiter();
    test_source_ends_with_delimiter();
    test_source_starts_and_ends_with_delimiter();
    test_small_output_size_stops_tokenising();
    test_large_output_size_stops_at_end_of_source();

    printf("done!\n");
}
```

[Online version](https://repl.it/repls/WorstUnsightlyApi).

- General feedback is welcome.
- Are there any missing tests / edge cases?
- Is there a better way to calculate the return size? (i.e. without the `start` variable`)
- Some things (the contents of `output` and `'\0'`s in the source) are tested as side-effects of the named test functions. Perhaps these should be separate named test cases?
- I usually do C++ stuff. Is there anything more C-ish that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tokenise()` function is clear and succinct; I can't find anything to dislike.  A couple of minor suggestions: wrap the declaration to a shorter line length, and consider changing the interface to terminate the `output` list with a null pointer (so that it's like `argv`).

It's great that you've included the unit tests for review.  I *love* unit tests!

I recommend using an established test framework for the tests.  It's fine to use a C++ unit-test framework for this, if we compile separately using `extern "C"` (as in [this answer of mine](/a/208558)).  The big advantage you'll get is better diagnostics when tests fail: instead of just `failed!` in the output, you'll see *which* test failed, and the actual and expected values that caused the failure.

Yes, you can write your own `EXPECT()` macro (and I sometimes do, to make a simple test harness), but you'll find over time that it drifts towards the functionality of the existing unit-test libraries.

You might want to add a function/macro to test the output list of strings, to simplify this repetition:

> ```
> test(strcmp(output[0], "a") == 0);
> test(strcmp(output[1], "bbb") == 0);
> test(strcmp(output[2], "cccc") == 0);
> test(strcmp(output[3], "dd") == 0);
> ```

If you're writing the tests in C++, you get to use standard collections to make that side of things more readable:

```c++
test_strings_eq({"a", "bbb", "cccc", "dd"}, output);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Allow query**

`tokenise()` obliges the calling code to know the maximum possible number of token prior to calling the function.

With judicious use of `strspn(), strcspn()`, the function could provide the return value of  `tokenise()` without disturbing `char* source` past `output_size`.

With 2 passes:

```
size_t token_count = tokenise(source, delimiters, NULL, 0);
char** output = malloc(sizeof *ouput *token_count); 
tokenise(source, delimiters, output, token_count);
```

**Quiet pedantic sign-ness change**

`output - start` results in a  signed integer type `ptrdiff_t`.  OP's code silently converts to an unsigned type `size_t`.  To quiet a picky compiler setting, apply a cast.

> warning: conversion to 'size_t {aka long unsigned int}' from 'long int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]

```
//return output - start;
return (size_t) (output - start);
```

**Coding error in comment**

```
//char[] src = "a b c";
char src[] = "a b c";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you make the function `main()` return with `EXIT_FAILURE` for a failed test case, the test cases will behave more nicely in automated environments (shell scripts, Makefiles, CI/CD pipelines, etc).

The `test()` function could use `fprintf(stderr, "failed!\n");` instead of `printf("failed!\n");` because that's what `stderr` is for.

Also, the `test()` function could be a macro instead, using `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__func__` identifiers to give a nicer error message about the failing test case, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

#define test(condition) \
    do { \
        if (!(condition)) { \
            fprintf( \
                stderr, \
                "%s: %d: error: Test case %s failed.\n", \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__ \
            ); \
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        } \
    } while(0)
```

And in `main()` `return status;`

And once that's done, the `test()` function/macro actually looks pretty redundant with the already existing `assert()` macro from `<assert.h>`. You could simply use that instead of `test()`, if you're okay with the downside of `assert()` that it calls `abort()` right away and consecutive test cases won't be executed. (You could work around that by inserting an abort handler, but that's probably overkill in this scenario.)

(Or use an existing unit test framework.)

Answer (score 1):

If you represent each token as a `struct` containing a pointer to the start and a length, you won’t need to modify the original string at all. Most modern C and C++ APIs request a string length instead of searching for a terminating `\0`, because it’s more secure, and it also makes calculating the string length trivial instead of linear-time.  The collection could then be a vector of these spans.

Answer (score 0):

LGTM.

A nitpick: testing for parameters being not-`NULL` is not enough. They may still being invalid (e.g. pointing to illegal places, or `source` being read-only). For true safety, consider catching `SIGSEGV`.